# How to call action of child component on parent events in ember JS

Tags: ember.js

I know we can call action of parent component from child component, but what I want here is reverse of it. 
I have a parent component , inside of it I have a child component so I am trying to trigger action of child component on parent components events.
I tried with `sendAction` but no luck.

Comment: you don't. thats against the DDAU pattern. can you elaborate *why* you want to do it? then we maybe can suggest another solution.

Comment: if you still want to do this action handling fashion, check out https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Evented

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Action can only bubble upwards, not downwards. From the [docs](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action):

> If the context of a template is a controller, actions used this way will bubble to routes when the controller does not implement the specified action. Once an action hits a route, it will bubble *[up]* through the route hierarchy.

Although this doc does talk about 'normal' route-controller-actions, the same applies to component-actions. I think you need to restructure your code, because there should never be a need to call an action to a child route/component.

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies since at least 1.13 and was written as of 3.x.

You cannot trigger an action on a child component from the parent route. However, you could make a Service that can be injected and used by both the route and the component, across routes, and between sibling components.

[Service docs in The Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/current/applications/services/)

It’s good to be cautious when you’re sharing state/functionality in this way, and ask yourself if there’s a simpler, more direct way to handle events. I use services sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying in **NO WAY** do I promote doing this, as there are better solutions.

Despite it being against the DDAU of Ember it is possible to do. Basically you need to register your child components to your parent so you can access their methods and actions. I have seen some very complicated situations where something like the approach below is needed. I would only recommend this as a last resort.

Child components didInsertElement hook:

```
...
didInsertElement(){
    this.get('parentView').register(this);
}
```

Parent component code:

```
...
child: null,
register(child){
    //you would push the children to some array here
    //or if you only have one child you could just set a property
    this.set('child', child);
}
```

This allows your parent component to have direct access to the children, which allows you to send your actions to them. Like below.

```
...
this.get('child').send('some-action');
```

Note: have not tested this code myself so it may need some tweaks.

**EDIT**:

I got this mostly from back when Ember deprecated "childViews". This was the proposed solution for applications that relied on it. This github conversation elaborates on the issue a little more. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11244

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, it may be feasible to set a computed property in the component to watch data that's changed externally. In other words, your component can be triggered to do something by a change in data that happened outside of it, following the data-down/actions-up convention.

Example:

```
// parent.hbs
{{my-component watchedValue=someDynamicValue}}

// my-component.js
computedValue: computed('watchedValue', function() {
    let watchedValue = get(this, 'watchedValue');

    // optionally do something...

    // ...and/or optionally send an action internally
    this.send('updateStuff', watchedValue);

    //return something (arbitrary value in this example)
    return watchedValue;
}),

actions: {
    updateStuff(value) {
        // do something
    }
}

// my-component.hbs
<p>The value is currently {{computedValue}}</p>
```

Note that [computed properties will only recompute when they are consumed](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_computed-properties-only-recompute-when-they-are-consumed), so although `computedValue` doesn't have to be used in the template, it's either that or using `get()` on it somewhere. Also note that this particular example introduces [side effects](https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/no-side-effects.md), which may not be desirable.