# how to call parent component method from child component in ember js

Tags: ember.js

I know about action down and data up strategy in Ember but is there a way I can call parent component method (not action) from child component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095295/how-to-call-action-of-child-component-on-parent-events-in-ember-js. It's essentially the same concept despite it being a method and not an action.

Comment: If you read my answer on that question, all you have to change is how you invoke the action. so it would be something like "this.get('child').myMethod()"

Comment: Here's the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158882/ember-component-call-an-action-in-a-route-or-controller

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G48DzGMaZ7M

Answer (score 4):

Well, I am using in this way if I would like to call a parent method from child:

Parent component.hbs:

```
{{component-name owner=this}}
```

Parent component.js:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    parentMethod(){
        // I am doing something
    }
});
```

Child component.js

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    didInsertElement(){
        this.get('owner').parentMethod();
    }
});
```

In this case this is not action.

Answer (score 1):

As per i know there is no direct way, but you can achieve same behavior with global event bus.

Create a new service using Ember.Service that will act as an event bus using Ember.Evented. Using this service parent component can publish events and child components can now subscribe these events without referencing the parent component

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.